# Alternatives to Jaccard Distance

Tags: set, cluster-analysis, distance, information-retrieval

To calculate the distance between two sets of words I am using the jaccard distance:

```
JaccardDistance(A, B) = 1 - JaccardIndex(A, B) = 1 - (|A ∩ B| / |A ∪ B|)
```

Now I wonder, are there other similar distance metrics that return values ​​between [0, 1]?

Where 0 it means that the two sets contain exactly the same elements while 1 completely different elements. The two sets may have different sizes and the order of words is not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common distance measure between two sets (more generally, multi-sets) is the *cosine distance* (which is the *angle*) between the vector representations of the multi-sets.

Now let's see how you can represent a multi-set as a vector.

The first step is to representing each set as a bag if its members, e.g.

X = {a, b, a, c} ==> (a:2) (b:1) (c:1)
Y = {d, b, a, d} ==> (a:1) (b:1) (d:2)

Each set is thus represented as a sparse vector of membership weights of the union set of all the members. For instance, the universal set of members in the above example is {a, b, c, d}, and the implicit weights of d and c in X and Y are 0.

With this sparse representation, which is convenient to store as a hashmap, you could then compute the cosine distance which is the arccos (inverse cosine) of the cosine similarity of the two vectors.

For two vectors **x**, **y**, the cosine similarity is computed as \sum_i x_i.y_i/(|**x**||**y**|), i.e. inner product of **x** and **y** divided by the product of the lengths of **x** and **y**.

In our example, the numerator is computed as 2x1 (product of the weight of member a in X and Y) + 1x1 + 1x0 + 2x0 = 3.

The length of **x** is sqrt(2x2+ 1x1 + 1x1) = sqrt(6), and it is easy to see that the length of **y** is also sqrt(6).

Hence cosine-distance = 3/(sqrt(6)*sqrt(6)) = 1/2, or in other words the *angle* between the vectors is 60 degrees.

Note: It is more common to omit the arccos operation and directly use the cosine similarity as a similarity (inverse distance) measure between multi-sets (represented as vectors).